# Contar cuantas veces se repite un nodo en prolog

Tags: prolog

```
conexion(d,h,4).
conexion(h,f,9).
conexion(i,f,11).
conexion(f,g,10).
conexion(f,a,8).
conexion(a,b,7).

tieneArista(X) :-conexion(X,_,_).
```

Quiero saber por ejemplo este código me dice que f se repite 2 veces quiero saber como buscarlo.
Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: buscar que?, si quieres obtener respuestas de calidad proporciona tambien preguntas de calidad, porfavor.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar [findall/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3) para encontrar todas las repeticiones de, lo que tu llamas nodos, y crear una lista con ellos. Después sólo contar la cantidad de elementos de esa lista. Por ejemplo:

```
conexion(d,h,4). 
conexion(h,f,9). 
conexion(i,f,11). 
conexion(f,g,10). 
conexion(f,a,8). 
conexion(a,b,7).


tieneArista(X) :- findall(X, conexion(X,_,_), L), length(L,N), writeln(N).
```

Ejecución:

```
?- tieneArista(f).
2
true.

?- tieneArista(h).
1
true.
```